# functions.https.onCall access to the req param from the http call

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am referring the following function
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

The syntax is:-

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```

Is there an option to get the req param we have in the standard http function

```
exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // ...
});
```

specifically interested in

```
req.protocol
req.get("host")
```

Comment: please select Doug's reply as the selected answer. It's correct.

Comment: @TheeBen the answer is not correct since it doesn't refer to the asked questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Callables don't support redirects.  They're expected to send direct responses to the client (otherwise, they wouldn't be "callable").

If you want to send a redirect to the client, use regular HTTP triggers with an HTTP client that can follow redirects (or handle the redirect yourself).

Comment: in my case, I simply need to build the redirect url and path it next, I don't call the redirect

Comment: Then send the redirect URL in the success response, and code the client app to find an follow it.  Consider sending just the path part of the URL instead of the full URL.