# How do I send a redirect as response from onCall function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to implement `paypal-rest-sdk` using a direct call from the application, using `onCall()`. According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable/), the answer must be a `JSON` object, which will include the data returned by the server. But what happens if I want to send a redirect as a response, such as when using `onRequest((req, res)` `res.redirect(302, url)`?

Comment: Why do you need to send a 302?  Are you trying to implement a webhook callback from Paypal?

Comment: @DougStevenson,you can put the code and the url you want, that `res.redirect()` is there to illustrate that with the so-called `onRequest((req, res)=>{})` it provides a way to respond 'res' to which you can tie the `redirect(server_code, url)` function, but `onCall` must return a `JSON` and only a `JSON`, and I need to send a redirection order, not a `JSON`.

Comment: @DougStevenson Someone has tried a [similar approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51739447/7774027), but I see that simply can not, because the "callable" functions do not support redirection.